# Does nuget have a solution for including packages that depend on different versions of one package?

Tags: .net, nuget

I am already using the `DocumentFormat.Ooxml` package and would like to also use `ClosedXml` which depends on an older version of the same library so I get:

```
PM> Install-Package closedxml
Attempting to resolve dependency 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml (= 1.0)'.
Installing 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml 1.0'.
Successfully installed 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml 1.0'.
Installing 'ClosedXML 0.69.2'.
Successfully installed 'ClosedXML 0.69.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Already referencing a newer version of 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml'.
```

Does nuget actually have a solution for this situation? Even if I could do assembly redirection (which I've always had mixed results with in unit tests) I don't see a `-Force` parameter on `Install-Package`.

**Edit:** Cross posted on the [nuget discussion board](https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/528923)

Comment: Can you use an older version of `DocumentFormat.ooxml`?

Comment: @MatthewSkelton maybe? Do I have to?

Comment: Well, this seems to be a fundamental package dependency issue (not really specific to NuGet). If using an older version of the problematic package resolves the dependency conflict, that seems like a reasonable approach to me.

Comment: @MatthewSkelton that's not true, many package managers handle this issue quite gracefully see npm or gems. I realize that .Net is a different beast but it is still possible to load different versions of an assembly (I did this recently with log4net) or at least to automatically set up assembly redirection. This is a problem that *has* to get solved for large package ecosystems to flourish and I'm sure the nuget team has spent time thinking about it. I'm trying to find out the status of things.

Comment: My question remains: can you simply use a previous version of the problematic package? If that solves the dependency problem, that's good, right?

Comment: @MatthewSkelton I can also (and did) use a different excel-creation package but this is a problem that I've encountered before and I'm sure I will again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no plans at current for allowing multiple versions of a package to be installed into a single project at once.  This would generally lead to conflicts as there would need to be 2 assemblies with the same name referenced (and in the bin folder).

The issue here is that ClosedXML has a version-specific dependency on DocumentFormat.OpenXml.  You can contact the owner of ClosedXML to see if they can publish a new version that allows for different versions of DocumentFormat.OpenXml to be used.

If that isn't successful, then you can try to break yourself out of this conflict by doing the following:

1. Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml [to get to your starting point]
2. Install-Package ClosedXML -ignoreDependencies [to install it, ignoring its dependencies]

This will result in a binding redirect getting added to your app/web.config file, like this:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.5631.0" newVersion="2.5.5631.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Then you'll need to test your consumption of ClosedXML to see if the newer version of DocumentFormat.OpenXml can really be used with it.  If it works, you'll certainly want to let the owners of ClosedXML know that (using the Contact Owners link on www.nuget.org for the package), so that they might move forward with updating the package with a new version that allows the newer DocumentFormat.OpenXml.